# Use twig Var in for loop

Tags: templating

```
the var menutype is set to {{ menutype }}

{% for block in menutype.menuGlobal %}
```

I'm trying to pass the result of {{ menutype }} into the for loop to return a dynamic menu, but the loop doesn't run. Hardcoding the string works, so the loop is fine, just appears not to recognise the variable output in the for statement.

Comment: What is the data you have assigned to {{ menutype }}? Is it a Navee object? Is it a custom field? Is it a structure? Give a bit more info here on what that data is and i'll be able to help. Also, do you have devmode on?

Comment: Could you post more of your code? What does the variable `menutype` look like? Does it have `menuGlobal` as a child in it?

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following code:

```
{% set dynamicMenu = menutype~".menuGlobal" %}

{% for block in dynamicMenu %}
.
.
.
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for Twig's [attribute](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/attribute.html) method.

```
{% for block in attribute(menutype, menuGlobal) %}
```

It allows you to get dynamic attributes off of a variable.